# Convert associate array (and foreach loop) to array without key (and while loop?)

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following PHP code that replaces folder names in the URL structure, for easy switching of languages whilst staying on the current page:

```
<?php
    $langs = array(
        "en/" => "en.png",
        "de/" => "de.png",
        "fr/" => "fr.png"
    );
    $self    = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    $pattern = "{^.*/}i";
    $links   = array();
    foreach ($langs as $folder => $flag) {
        $url  = preg_replace($pattern, "$folder", $self);
        $link = "<li><a href=\"../$url\"><img src=\"../img/$flag\"></a></li>";
        array_push($links, $link);
    }
    echo implode($links) . "\n";
?>
```

However, I've realised that with a simple array reading `$langs = array("en", "de", "fr");` I could possibly save a few bytes and simplify the bottom-half of the code, reusing the variables for the folder and for the image? Would this be a better way of doing things? And how?

This is what I have so far, but the `$langs['$x']` seems wrong? (In fact, I get a syntax error on my loop conditions!):

```
$langs = array("en", "de", "fr");
$n = count($langs); // 3
while ($x = 0; $x < $n; $x++ ) {
    $folder = $langs['$x'] . "/";
    $flags = $langs['$x'] . ".png";
    echo $folder . " " . $flags; // test
}
```

Comment: Why does "saving a few bytes" matter?

Comment: Not only am I trying to get my code as small as possible, I'm trying to build a template system for our websites that is as fool-proof as possible. By "forcing" people to use particular folder structures/image names, it will mean that rolling out new sites should be much simpler, with far fewer lines of code being touched.

Comment: @MatthewPeckham, why not use an existing templating system? There are lots to choose from.

Comment: Unfortunately, we cannot redesign the sites we're working with. All I can do is improve and "automate" existing code; tidy up CSS, move common terms to variables and then to includes, translations to .ini files, etc.

Comment: Consider asking this on codereview.stackexchange.com. I can make some other suggestions, but they aren't on topic for this question.

Comment: Here we are: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/41075/simplifying-an-associative-array. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert an associative array to a numerically-indexed array with [`array_values`](https://www.php.net/array_values):

```
$array = array('a' => 'A', 'b' => 'B', 'c' => 'C');

// array(0 => 'A', 1 => 'B', 2 => 'C');
$new_array = array_values($array);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because you are using the wrong quotes, double quotes are required for variable substitution

```
$langs = array("en", "de", "fr");
$n = count($langs); // 3
while ($x = 0; $x < $n; $x++ ) {
    $folder = $langs["$x"] . "/";
    $flags = $langs["$x"] . ".png";
    echo $folder . " " . $flags; // test
}
```